# Using replace() multiple times with different variable

Tags: javascript

I am using `` "[TITLE] [STORENAME] [DYNAMIC]".replace(regex, `$1|${replace}=${value}]`); `` multiple times but everytime before I use it, I change the variable `replace`. See the full code:

```js
obj = {} || obj;
const replace = 'prefix';
let search = 'TITLE';
const value = 'MY VALUE';
const regex = new RegExp(`(\\[${search}(?:\\|[^\\][]*)?)]`, 'gi');

obj.str = "[TITLE] [STORENAME] [DYNAMIC]".replace(regex, `$1|${replace}=${value}]`);

search = 'STORENAME';
obj.str = "[TITLE] [STORENAME] [DYNAMIC]".replace(regex, `$1|${replace}=${value}]`);

search = 'DYNAMIC';
obj.str = "[TITLE] [STORENAME] [DYNAMIC]".replace(regex, `$1|${replace}=${value}]`);

console.log(obj.str);
```

So as you see I get the result `[TITLE|prefix=MY VALUE] [STORENAME] [DYNAMIC]` but the goal is to get this result: `[TITLE|prefix=MY VALUE] [STORENAME|prefix=MY VALUE] [DYNAMIC|prefix=MY VALUE]`.

Probably it is because I use the same string for `replace()` all over again but I have also tried it this way:

```js
obj = {} || obj;
obj.str = '[TITLE] [STORENAME] [DYNAMIC]';

const replace = 'prefix';
let search = 'TITLE';
const value = 'MY VALUE';

const regex = new RegExp(`(\\[${search}(?:\\|[^\\][]*)?)]`, 'gi');

obj.str = obj.str.replace(regex, `$1|${replace}=${value}]`);

search = 'STORENAME';
obj.str = obj.str.replace(regex, `$1|${replace}=${value}]`);

search = 'DYNAMIC';
obj.str = obj.str.replace(regex, `$1|${replace}=${value}]`);

console.log(obj.str);
```

But the output is still not correct.

Comment: Once `const regex = new RegExp(`(\\[${search}(?:\\|[^\\][]*)?)]`, 'gi');` runs it is set in stone... It will not update when you change the variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this code:

```js
obj = {} || obj;
obj.str = '[TITLE] [STORENAME] [DYNAMIC]';

const replace = 'prefix';
const value = 'MY VALUE';

obj.str.split(" ").forEach(function(val){
  let search = val.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
  let regex = new RegExp(`(\\[${search}(?:\\|[^\\][]*)?)]`, 'gi');
  obj.str = obj.str.replace(regex, `$1|${replace}=${value}]`);
})


console.log(obj.str);
```

Answer (score 1):

You assume the reg exp updates automatically. It does not, you would need to make a reg exp for each one.

Use a look up object with a generic reg exp.

```js
var replacements = {
 FOO: "Hello",
 BAR: "World",
 BAZ: "Funky Pants"
};

var reExp = /\[([^\]]+)\]/g;

// function replaceIt(str, replacements) {
//  return str.replace(reExp, function (match) {
//    return replacements[match.substring(1, match.length-1)] || match;
//  });
// }

function replaceIt(str, replacements) {
  return str.replace(reExp, function (match) {
    var key = match.substring(1, match.length-1);
    var text = replacements[key];
    if (!text) return match
    return `[${key}|prefix=${text}]`;
  });
}

console.log(replaceIt("[FOO] [BAR] [BAZ]", replacements));
console.log(replaceIt("[FOO] [BAR] [CHEESE]", replacements));
```